# Portal users logged in outside of login hours

Tags: login, portal

Portal profile login hours were set to 12 AM PDT to 3 PM PDT. At 3 PM all the existing user sessions were removed through session management. But some users were able to login after 3 PM. I never encountered such scenario. Any possible reasons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue. When I deployed a changeset from sandbox, I included some newly created fields and also added the profiles to the changeset hoping that profile settings of the fields will be carried over to production and everything else remains unchanged. But I didn't know that login hours will be affected. I did some test deployments between my sandboxes and noticed login hours getting overridden.

Answer (score 0):

Has there been any changes done to the orgs default time zone after you set the user profiles time zone?
The first time login hours are set for a profile, the hours are based on the organization’s Default Time Zone as specified on the Company Information page in Setup. After that, any changes to the organization’s Default Time Zone won’t change the time zone for the profile’s login hours. As a result, the login hours are always applied at those exact times even if a user is in a different time zone or if the organization’s default time zone is changed.